# What is the best practice in Angular 12+ to load an object and have it available in other components?

Tags: angular

In an Angular (version 12 or above) app, when the user "Logs In", using, say, a REST API or OAuth login, I want to hold the "User" object in memory until the user explicitly "Logs Out".

And, I want each component to have access to it (if it wants to), without having to load it again.

There are a number of ways that I have done this in the past, including holding values in Local Storage.

But what is the best way, recommended by the framework, understandable by the developer community, to hold what are variables with Application-wide scope across components?

Comment: You could use a state library (but if you have only this object, it would be an overkill, I think). Beside that you can use a `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject` in a service. At login you emit the user object and every subscriber will get it and can use it.

Comment: Either a store like ngrx, or a service that is available at the root level which keeps track of the user object.

Comment: LocalStorage is useful if you want the data to survive to page close. Else is fine to keep the data in memory using a service IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, if you want to go with straight Angular and no additional libraries, a service that uses the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` seems to make the most sense to me. As has already been pointed out, this has the added benefit of holding onto the data in case of a page refresh which is worth its weight in gold since you can't predict the user's interaction with your app. Also, I think even non Angular developers could see that and understand how it works without too much issue.